# AngularJS data-binding inside of dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can I use databinding for dependency injection? I'd like to pass the services I want to call on the JSON file being delivered to the AngularJS application.

```
app.directive('directiveName', ['{{ Data.servName }}','lookupService', function () {};])
```

Can I use databinding in this method?

Answer (score 0):

No, and that sounds like a terrible idea. Your REST api shouldn't be tightly coupled like this to your angular client implementation.

Anyway, if you has the name of a service and want to get this service instance, inject the [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector) service, and call its `get()` method with the service name as argument.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately it's not my design call, so I don't question it.